# How to divide a rectangle into equally sized parts each connected to the perimeter?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm doing the Viewshed algorithm in a map reduce setting and have a pretty solid algorithm in mind (http://www.geoinfo.info/proceedings_geoinfo2013.split/paper9.pdf), in order for it to work I need to have something in the lines of the following algorithm I will explain now:

Input: Number of desired areas *N*, a raster (just a matrix) *R*, and a point in the raster/matrix *P*

Output: *N* areas where each area is a polygon (triangle or 4-cornered polygon), where one corner is at *P*, and the other corners are connected to the perimeter of *R*.

So let me show you an example:

The output could be like this where *P* is in the center:
[image: *P* is in the centre]

Obviously *P* doesn't need to be in the center.

Does anybody know any good algorithms for this?

Comment: Raster? Why do you need a raster to define a rectangle?

Comment: I don't need a raster to define it, that's just what I have now. If you can create an algorithm which as input just takes four points (or even just width and height) to represent the rectangle then sure that works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general algorithm could go like this:

- find the area of every of the N polygons ( obviously it is area of R divided by N )
- create vertical segment from P to the top left corner of R
- having this segment as first edge of new polygon move clockwise along R border with given small step and calculate area of new polygon
- if area is close to area of every polygon create it
- use last edge as first edge of new polygon and repeat.

If you need perfect precision you could also calculate exact position of new point as you have all necessary data. Every of those polygons is convex and can be subdivided into number of triangles.

Below some illustration, hope it helps:[image]

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm going for, thanks for writing it down though. Thanks!